# Homepage direct to password login

Tags: wordpress

I've searched but I can't find a way change our homepage and login as we'd like. What I'd like have is our logo on our homepage. When someone clicked on the logo it would direct them to a login page. I've seen this done on many sites but can't find an add-in that does this. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where have you seen this? Can you share some knowledge so we can go from there?

Comment: It's used here   https://www.moorecap.com/MOORE/WEB/me.get?web.home

Comment: you can try changing it in header.php

Answer (score 0):

to change img src on logo div\href in ur theme -> change src in ./themes/[ur-theme]/style.css

to change link on ur "logo" href - go to header.php in theme folder dir and find it there... but don't forget to check is user already logged in before redirecting it to login page... u can check it with http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in